# Running a sample using Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to run a sample example using Laravel 4 and i am getting errors like, class not found. Can someone help me out here?

controller
file name : authors.php

```
<?php

class Authors extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index() {
        return View::make('authors.index');
    }   
}
?>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

Views/authors/index.php

```
<h1> First program in Laravel 4 </h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fitst of all your authors!=Authors, so make sure of your conyroller name in the Route.

And if you want RESTful controller then you can define your route like `Route::controller('baseURI','ControllerName')`,

> Laravel allows you to easily define a single route to handle every action in a controller using simple, REST naming conventions. First, define the route using the Route::controller method.. 
>   To know more check [restful-controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)

In your example you have to rename your get_index method to getIndex as L4 is camelCase

```
//AuthorsController.php
class AuthorsController extends BaseController {

public $restful = true;

public function getIndex() {
    return View::make('authors.index');
}   
}

//route.php
Route::controller('authors', 'AuthorsController');
```

Comment: can you post the exact code some where, try paste.laravel.com? on which line?

Comment: sorry my bad, I have corrected the answer, its Route::controller not Route::get